# React not updating state when sending backend request

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

**Problem Description:** I've been trying to make my component update whenever I send a request to the backend. I got 3 requests on my backend now (create, update and delete), when I create an item it updates normally, however when I update or delete one, it simply won't update the data.

**Scenario:**

I have a hook calling on the first render:

```
useEffect(() => {
    refreshData();
}, []);
```

For updating on request sent I have refreshData function:

```
const refreshData = async () => {
    let enums = await api.get('users/enum');
    setUsersEnum(enums.data);
    let equipments = await api.get('equipments/fixo');
    setData(equipments.data);
};
```

For CUD actions I got this functions:

*PS: This functions are called upon button action.*

```
const handleNew = async (e) => {
    modalAddNew(!addNew);
    let form = { ...addForm };
    if (form.warranty !== '') {
        form = {
            ...form,
            maintenance: {
                warranty: form.warranty,
                maintainer: form.maintainer,
                details: form.details,
            },
        };
    }
    delete form.warranty;
    delete form.maintainer;
    delete form.details;
    await api.post('equipments', form);
    await refreshData();

    handleChangeAddForm({
        id: '',
        brand: '',
        type: '',
        specs: '',
        user_id: '2041',
        category: enums.categories.default,
        status: 'FIXO',
        warranty: '',
        details: '',
        maintainer: '',
    });
};

const handleEdit = (id) => {
    setModalEdit(!modalEdit);
    let form = { ...editForm };
    delete form.id;
    delete form.department;
    delete form.description;
    delete form.specs;
    api.patch(`equipments/${id}`, form).then((response) => {
        refreshData();
        console.log('test');
    });
    handleChangeEditForm({
        id: '',
        user_id: '2041',
        description: '',
        department: 'NTI',
        status: 'FIXO',
        warranty: '',
        details: '',
        maintainer: '',
    });
};

const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    setModalEdit(!modalEdit);
    await api.delete(`equipments/${id}`);
    await refreshData();
};
```

**Tried solutions:**

- First thing I did was trying only to call refreshData function
  whenever I finished a request (didn't work).
- After that I tried useEffect + useState with a changing variable (didn't work)

**How should it work:** Whenever I made a request, the state should change so I could visualize it without refreshing the page myself. How would be the proper approach? Please share only thoughts not solutions.

Obs: You see that `console.log('test');` in the patch request callback? It won't log on terminal no matter what. Backend requests works though.

Comment: Hi Gabe. Have you tried wrapper your handleRefresh function with useCallback?

Comment: Hey @CarlosQuerioz. Just did it. Won't call the function as well.

Comment: Another question is: If you log your state after an update and delete action, the state still the same? (Sorry for the late answer).

Comment: Logging data before and after shows the same content. Problem is that the funcion won't get called. I tried logging any text whenever the function is called but it won't log it. Fun fact is that I got two pages inside an app and both are using the same approach, in the first one I did things worked pretty well. [github](https://github.com/gabeleonn/fabapar-client)

Comment: @CarlosQuerioz, sorry forgot to tell you the pages to look at. [Loan pages](https://github.com/gabeleonn/fabapar-client/tree/main/src/Pages/Loans) is the one that does not work. [User pages](https://github.com/gabeleonn/fabapar-client/tree/main/src/Pages/Users) is the one that works.